# Get-Clipboard of Powershell : '-Raw' option?

Tags: powershell, text, command-line, clipboard

From microsoft document manual, I found an option for 'Get-Clipboard' of PowerShell.
The option is '-Raw' :

> -Raw : Gets the entire contents of the clipboard. Multiline text is returned as a single multiline string rather than an array of strings.

But I couldn't find any difference for adding '-Raw.
For example,

```
powershell.exe "Get-Clipboard -Format text " > MyText.txt
```

and

```
powershell.exe "Get-Clipboard -Format text -Raw" > MyText.txt
```

gives the same results. (Regardless of the content of the clipboard)
Can you give me an example such that the use of '-Raw' option makes something different ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$tempfile = New-TemporaryFile

@'
some 
different lines 
of text
'@ | Set-Content $tempfile

Get-Content $tempfile | Set-Clipboard

$text = Get-Clipboard

$text.count

3

$text = Get-Clipboard -Raw

$text.Count

1
```

As it said it is a single string, rather than an array of strings.

Here is one example of the many times it matters.

```
$text = Get-Clipboard

$text -match 'different'

different lines

$text = Get-Clipboard -Raw

$text -match 'different'

true
```